# Make a responsive table with sub-headings

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make a table with sub-headings and side headings responsive so the table looks great on mobile devices and displays all/partial of the results. I know this can be done easily with simple headings, but what I have, has sub-headings and side-headings attached.

Furthermore, is it possible of having the option of hiding unnecessary data from the table when it's in responsive mode?

Here's what I have so far with some help:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        table.zing {
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

            table.zing td, table.zing th {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }

            table.zing .FirstColumn {
                background-color: #9999dd;
            }

            table.zing thead tr {
                background-color: blue;
            }

            table.zing tbody.secondHeader tr {
                background-color: skyblue;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="zing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <colgroup>
            <col class="FirstColumn">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Object</th>
                <th colspan="2">Openings</th>
                <th colspan="3">Internal Dimensions</th>
                <th colspan="3">Weight</th>
                <th>Volume</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="secondHeader">
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Width</th>
                <th>Height</th>
                <th>Length</th>
                <th>Width</th>
                <th>Height</th>
                <th>Max</th>
                <th>Min</th>
                <th>Tare</th>
                <th>Capacity</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>20 std</td>
                <td>Small</td>
                <td>300</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>700</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>40 std</td>
                <td>Medium</td>
                <td>400</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>700</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>50 std</td>
                <td>Large</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>700</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>60 std</td>
                <td>X-Large</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>200</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>700</td>
                <td>100</td>
                <td>50</td>
                <td>2.1</td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Would appreciate some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to hiding columns when on particular devices consider adding classes to them, you can then write media queries to hide them for specific screen sizes:

Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .hide-phone{display:none}
}
```